# Genius 31310469100 Scorpion K5 Gaming Keyboard - Control and Alt Keys Function as shift, no shortcut keys (Ctrl+F, C, V etc) in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Pretty much the title (above keyboard in 20.04). I tried using

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and following through the prompt best I could, to no avail (exact keyboard isn't listed so I went w/ a standard 104-key keyboard). Also tried some stuff about turning off Locate Pointer in settings and making sure only one language was installed.

Any tips what to try next? New-ish to Linux/Ubuntu so I might need a dumbed down version (haven't used since 2012, picking back up for easier python use at work).

In case it's helpful:

```
$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 062a:4106 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G Wireless Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia USB Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

/etc/default/keybord

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Note: Can be solved using a user-developed driver, Ubuntu simply does not support this keyboard by default, [see here](https://github.com/teitss/aziokbd) note that the original bitbucket page seems to be dead, so you can copy the files from the newer git, which also fixes the backslash key

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Could you please edit you question and include the contents of `/etc/default/keyboard`?

Comment: I ended up solving this, but I actually forgot what precisely I followed. Was some kind of  driver somebody developed. The bitbucket page is missing, but digging deep enough i eventually found a reference to it that had active.

Comment: @adriaan added.

Comment: It seems that ubuntu just doesn't support the chipset for this keyboard properly. This is the solution I found (note the original bitbucket project seems to be down (so don't bother trying to clone it), but this one on github includes a fix for the backslash key as well so it's better. https://github.com/teitss/aziokbd